# Why is Spring hot swap not working?

Tags: spring

I'm running a Spring Application - everything works so far - except that changes are not reflected.

If I request `http://localhost:8080/test` I am getting the expected result, but if I make any changes to the code, the changes are not reflected.

I was following [these instructions](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with) but that didn't help either.

The REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public List<String> myTest() {
        System.out.print("hello");
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The application:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "at.dml.controller"})
public class ApplicationProvider {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationProvider.class, args);
    }

}
```

What do I have to do in order to let the application reflect changes to the code?

**Update:**

I now added the following, although it didn't help:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps carefully? Modified registry value for `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` ? Restarted IDE? See also [Spring Boot Dev Tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) reference for other details.

Comment: @naXa Yes, registry was edited as described and I also restarted the IDE. Idk what I'm missing ..

Comment: Try doing,  You need to update the project configuration manually. Project -> Maven -> Update Configuration and then, reinstall project, re-deploy your code and restart server

Comment: @AmitKBist Thank you. Apparently I was missing one of those steps or idk why it didn't work but now it does. Allthough, IntelliJ does not reload automatically yet. I have to **Ctrl + Shift + F9** in order to reload changed classes although I enabled automatic make. A bit weird..

Comment: @displayname If you have found an answer to your own question please post it here. It's [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) because it's easier for others to find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I added this to my pom.xml (see the update in my question) but it didn't help .. if I change the `System.out.print()` statement, nothing happens. Even manually re-compiling with **Ctrl + Shift + F9** does not help ..